Crystal Report If formula with multiple conditions
I'm getting an error message with this formula but can't see the wood for the trees of what's missing - please help!
if {vehinv_rec.master_class_2} = "RCV" and if {vehinv_rec.chassis_model} in
["DF01",
"DF02",
"DF03",
"DF04",
"DF05",
"DF06",
"DF07",
"DF08",
"DF09",
"DF10",
"DF11",
"DF12",
"DF13",
"DF14",
"DF15",
"DF16",
"DF17",
"DF18",
"DF19",
"DF20",
"FAD2",
"AN1",
"AN2",
"ANT",
"ME4"] then "Uncompliant" else
if {vehinv_rec.master_class_2} = "RCV" and {vehinv_rec.gvw_kg} > 18000 then "Compliant" else "Out of Scope"
I keep getting an error saying THEN is missing, but I can't see where?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You have a syntax error.  You wrote the formula as:
IF arg1 AND IF arg2 THEN...

Instead, try it as:
IF arg1 AND arg2 THEN...

When you repeated the keyword IF in the evaluation of arg2 the compiler/parser saw that as beginning a new IF statement without completing the first one.

Fantastic thank you - works a treat now!
